# A Continuity Argument in the Proof of Rouche's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

In Greene and Krantz's *Function Theory of One Complex Variable*, the proof of Rouche's theorem involves the following continuity argument.

> Let $f,g\colon U \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic from an open set $U$. Let $\bar{D}(p,r) \subseteq U$, and 
>   \begin{equation} 
> \vert f(\zeta) - g(\zeta) \vert \le \vert f(\zeta) + g(\zeta) \vert
> \end{equation} 
>   for $\zeta \in \partial D(p,r).$
>
> Define
>   $$ f_t (\zeta) = tf(\zeta) + (1-t)\,g(\zeta), $$
>   for $t\in [0,1]$. 
>   Then the integral 
>   $$ I_t = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\partial D(p,r)} \frac{f'_t (\zeta)}{f_t (\zeta)}\,d\zeta $$
>   is a continuous function of $t\in [0,1]$.

They add in parenthases that the denominator does not vanish and the integrand depends continuously on $t$.

**Question:** Would anyone be kind enough to supply the details behind this continuity of $I_t$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $$F(t,\zeta)={tf'(\zeta)+(1-t)g'(\zeta)\over tf(\zeta)+(1-t)g(\zeta)}$$
Since the denominator does not vanish, the function $F$ is continuous on $[0,1]\times \partial D(p,r)$. This is a *compact* set, so $F$ is in fact *uniformly* continuous in $(t,\zeta)$.

Now, let $\epsilon>0$ be given, and let $t_0 \in [0,1]$. By the uniform continuity, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $$|F(t,\zeta)-F(t_0,\zeta)|<\epsilon/r$$for all $t$ with $|t-t_0| < \delta$. It follows that
$$|I_t-I_{t_0}|\leq {1\over 2\pi}\Bigl|\int_{\partial D(p,r)}\bigl(F(t,\zeta)-F(t_0,\zeta)\bigr){\rm d}\zeta\Bigr| \leq {1\over 2\pi}\cdot {\epsilon\over r}\cdot 2\pi r=\epsilon $$
This means that $I_t$ is continuous with respect to $t$.