Does holomorphic functions $f,g$ have same number of zeros in Annulus if $\lambda f + (1 - \lambda)g \neq 0$ on boundary?
Suppose that $f,g : \mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{C}$ are holomorphic and let $Z(f)$ and $Z(g)$ be the number of zeros in the annulus $A_{R,r} := \{z \in \mathbb{C} : r < |z| < R\}$ counted with multiplicity, where $0 < r < R < 1$. If we moreover assume that $\lambda f + (1 - \lambda)g$ has no zeroes on $\partial A_{r,R}$ for any $\lambda \in [0,1]$, then is it true that
\begin{equation*}
    Z(f) = Z(g)
\end{equation*}
must hold?
So far i have looked at $h_\lambda(z) := \lambda f(z) + (1 - \lambda)g(z)$ and tried applying the argument principle and the showing that the resulting expression doesnt depend on $\lambda$, but i can't seem to get to the result.
I've also looked at trying to use intermediate value theorem if the zeros move continuisly as a function of $\lambda$

Possibly helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/206517/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2060370/42969.

this is a version of Rouche theorem using the argument principle and noting that since the number of zeroes is integral hence jumps by at least one when this number is different, for every $\lambda \in [0,1]$ we have an $\epsilon_{\lambda}$, st $h_{c}$ has the same number of zeroes as $h_{\lambda}$ when $|c-\lambda| \le \epsilon_{\lambda}, c \in [0,1]$ just majorizing trivially the integrals involved, using continuity, no zero of denominator etc; Since $[0,1]$ is compact, the usual finite subcover arguments shows that this implies that $h_0=g, h_1=f$ have same number of zeroes

yes -- just use the standard homologous form of Argument Principle -- i.e. w/ cycles  $\Gamma_f = (f\circ \gamma_r, f\circ \gamma_R)$ and $\Gamma_g = (g\circ \gamma_r, g\circ \gamma_R)$ with simple $\gamma_r$ negatively oriented around circle with radius $r$ and simple $\gamma_R$ positively oriented around circle with radius $R$, your homotopy criterion implies $n\big(f\circ\gamma_r\big)=n\big(g\circ\gamma_r\big)$ and $n\big(f\circ\gamma_R\big)=n\big(g\circ\gamma_R\big)$  hence $Z(f) =n\big(\Gamma_f,0\big) =  n\big(\Gamma_g,0\big)=Z(g)$
